# How do I fix a sticky scroll on a mobile responsive website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a mobile responsive website. 
I noticed that when scrolling the page using an iPhone, the scroll is sticky and not smooth, while on android mobiles it's ok.

**What can be the cause of this sticky scroll?** I cant even see it on my browser!  Please take a look at my code on JSfiddle. The images won't load but you don't need them anyway (you can see their borders). I recommend you to use 320px width to view the page so the icons are all organized.

Comment: What do you mean by "sticky"? Is it not smooth or you see some "jumping" elements?

Comment: @bwitkowicz not smooth, 
scroll-stops-scroll-stops, and not scroll and slides till it stops slowly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there is this line you can add to your body or the main div: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` 
Made the trick.